# Map a function to multiple data frames

Tags: r, purrr

I have a function that creates a new column in a dataframe repeating the name of the dataframe in every cell:

```
add_column_with_name <- function(x) {
    x$name <- deparse(substitute(x))
    return(x)
```

It works singly:

```
df_y <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
df_y <- add_columns_with_name(df_y)
df_y
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  x y     name1
<dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     df_y 
2     2 b     df_y 
3     3 c     df_y 
4     4 d     df_y
```

But the object name doesn't map when I pass the function as an argument to map to apply it to a list of dataframes:

```
df_x <- tibble(x = c(5,6,7,8), y = c('e', 'f', 'g', 'h'))
df_vector <- c(df_x, df_y)
result <- map_df(df_vector, add_column_with_name) 
result

# A tibble: 8 x 3
      x y     name1  
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
1     5 e     .x[[i]]
2     6 f     .x[[i]]
3     7 g     .x[[i]] 
4     8 h     .x[[i]]
5     1 a     .x[[i]]
6     2 b     .x[[i]]
7     3 c     .x[[i]]
8     4 d     .x[[i]]
```

I also tried a more elegant approach:

```
result <- map_df(df_vector, ~ mutate(., name = deparse(substitute(.))))
result

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  x y     name 
<dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     5 e     .    
2     6 f     .    
3     7 g     .    
4     8 h     .    
5     1 a     .    
6     2 b     .    
7     3 c     .    
8     4 d     .
```

I could've hard-coded the values in the time it took me to write this post but I think I'm missing something important! Is it possible the error lies in the use of deparse(substitute())?

Thanks

Comment: Look at your df_vector, there is no more footprints of the names df_x and df_y. That's normal : c evaluates its arguments.

Comment: As Nicolas2 hints, you need a list with named elements. If you have a named list, you can use `imap`. `named.list <- list(df_x=df_x, df_y=df_x); imap(named.list, ~mutate(.x, name1 = .y))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the df_x and df_y to be evaluated using quote :

```
purrr::map_df(list(quote(df_x),quote(df_y))
         , function(x) {y <- eval(x); y$name <- as.character(x); y})
## A tibble: 8 x 3
#      x y     name 
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1     5 e     df_x 
#2     6 f     df_x 
#3     7 g     df_x 
#4     8 h     df_x 
#5     1 a     df_y 
#6     2 b     df_y 
#7     3 c     df_y 
#8     4 d     df_y
```

Answer (score 2):

This solutions works, as long as you use proper`names` for the `list` elements:

```
df_y <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
df_x <- tibble(x = c(5,6,7,8), y = c('e', 'f', 'g', 'h'))

df_list <- list(df_y, df_x) # we create the list

names_list <- c("df_y", "df_x") # we need to name each element 

map2(df_list, names_list, function(x,y) {x$name = y # assignment
                                         x})
```

So, you just need to create the vector of the names of each `data.frame`. Then use `map2`, which maps a function to two vectors (`x,y`)

Output:

```
$`df_y`
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      x y     name 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     df_y 
2     2 b     df_y 
3     3 c     df_y 
4     4 d     df_y 

$df_x
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      x y     name 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     5 e     df_x 
2     6 f     df_x 
3     7 g     df_x 
4     8 h     df_x
```